# Docker with nodemon does not reload my api when code changes

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, nodemon

I've been working with docker some weeks ago and I was able to hold this issue, stop docker containers and start them over again to see the changes that I had made in my code but now is really anoying because every single change I do have to kill docker and then "docker-compose up".

However my friend is using the same container on his apple machine but when he makes changes to any server side code he does not have to restart his app.
I can see the changes when I go into the container but those changes are not reflected on live(browser).

My Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.11.3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
# Copy application files
COPY tools ./tools/
COPY migrations ./migrations/
COPY seeds ./seeds/
# Attempts to copy "build" folder even if it doesn't exist
COPY .env build* ./build/

RUN npm install -g nodemon

RUN git clone https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it.git
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nodemon", "-L",  "server"]
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
api:
    build: ./
    hostname: api
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - "${APP_PORT}:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    command: node tools/run.js
```

Any sugestion?